# Elasticsearch: Only push new document when there are no similar documents

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity

A few sentences about my use case:

I'm collecting a couple of articles and I am storing them in a db. Those docs consist of a title. Before I push the document to the db, I'd like to make sure that there are no similar entries in the db - in one query. So it should only store the document when it's unique.

If that's not possible, how can I retrieve only one document even if other (similar) documents exist?

I'm doing that already with mongodb and some JS code that checks for String similarity, but I'd rather remove that code so that Elasticsearch can make use of that. So I'm planning to move from mongodb to Elasticsearch.

I hope you guys can help me - and thank you very much in advance! :)

Regards,

Sascha

Comment: [more_like_this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) should get you a few steps ahead.

Comment: Hey @Val, thanks for your reply. So the MLT query can only be used for the GET-Request right? So it can not be combined with the PUT request, can it? Thx in advance.